# GPU lockup on nvidia GeForce 8200m G

Tags: installation, nvidia, live-usb, gpu

I have recently installed 12.04 LTS on an old Toshiba Satellite A215 which works just fine.  I am attempting to load Ubuntu on an MSI CR600 with a GeForce 8200m G video controller (I am trying to dump Microsoft once and for all).  I've attempted to install both 12.04 and 12.10, on disk (32 bit), failing before reaching the install screen each time.

If I install, via usb, can I add the necessary drivers and other needed deb packages to the usb stick, prior to install?  I could download the necessary files thru my Toshiba Satellite A215 but I would ask for a bit of guidance, since I am fairly new to Linux.

Comment: Try to find the performance settings of the card in BIOS and if exist, change it to "on demand". Then 3D cards are enabled only when it is necessary, otherwise running in savings mode, which is much more friendly to Ubuntu installer. You can add Nvidia proprietal drivers later after system will be up and running. Cannot find the NTB/card specs to confirm it as solution, so therefore I add just a comment here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dee.  Didn't think about trying it that way.  May have worked though.  See below. I appreciate your input.

Comment: Close voters: This question has a good answer. **There is no need to close this**.

Answer (score 2):

Realizing that I needed to turn the native nvidia drivers off to be able to see the screen; after changing boot sequence, I quickly tapped <kbd>F6</kbd> key to get into the Linux screen.

I checked `nomodeset` to disable the native video controller and hit <kbd>esc</kbd>.  I was then able to install 12.04 LTS, using linux video drivers.  After installing OS, I then installed Synaptic: googled Linux drivers for GeForce 8800m G.  Downloaded from Asia nVidia site. US site doesn't have them.  Installed the Linux drivers for the video controller.